# Keep original value in input field and get new value when user changes via AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

Creating `laravel` application and this is my scenario. I am displaying previously store value from database in forms like this,

`<input id="phone" name="phone" type="text" value="{{ $user->phone }}" class="validate">`

And fetching the values using ajax like this,

```
<script>
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
    var phone = $('input[name="phone"]').val();
    var options = {
        "amount": "100",
        "notes": {
            "order_phone" : phone,
        },
        "handler": function (response){
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "{{ route('payment') }}",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                "id": response.id,
            },
            success: function (r) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        })  
        },
    };
</script>
```

I am using `phone` value for post request via ajax, the problem is whenever user types on the input field, I'm not getting the new value from the input field and always getting old values.

Please do guide me how to get newly inputed or changed value from the input using ajax.

Comment: The above code will only be executed once (on page load). If you want it to react when the user types, you should to set up an event listener in JS that reacts to changes on the input field. Also, since your input has an id, you could just fetch the value using: `$('#phone').val()` instead.

Comment: ...btw, the posted code isn't _using_ ajax in any way. It's only adding a header to the default ajax settings.

Comment: that code showed as an example in laravel documentetion to add X-CSRF-TOKEN https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/csrf  So, I think it takes phone as a token.

Comment: Search for ajax, post, request and get methods atleast do somehing with ajax :)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson ya i know, i just posted few codes which i need clarification.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i have updated the code, check now